# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\a\1\s\node_modules\quill'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngx-quill

ngx-quill on prod does not work anyone has an idea ? I have using  "ngx-quill": "^13.4.0", it could not find quill but does work locally.

It does not work on the pipeline..

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\b\565\s\node_modules\quill'

how do we run npm install again on the pipeline badi ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyN5o.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmPR.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the package of quill specially for ngx. **So you can uninstall quill or ngx-quill before and clean what you installed**.

Then :

```
npm install ngx-quill
```

import the QuillModule

```
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill'
```

And QuillModule in the NgModule you want use quill :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,

    QuillModule.forRoot()
  ],
  ...
})
class YourModule { ... }
```

Comment: It works fine locally Sir , there is no issue on the modules and the quill package that was installed. The issue is when I push the code on the pipeline , the pipeline fails with that error
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\b\565\s\node_modules\quill'

Comment: What's happen when you uninstall all and reinstall locally? (delete all node_modules and npm install)

Comment: I installed "ngx-quill": "^13.4.0" since my angular version is 11

Comment: I did not uninstall and reinstall it locally since there is no issue on the local